# Show that $|\lambda|\leq 1$ for each eigenvalue $\lambda$ of a partial isometry

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

Let $V$ be an inner product space. A linear map $U:V\rightarrow V$ is a *partial isometry* if there is a subspace $M\subset V$ such that $\parallel Ux\parallel =\parallel x \parallel$ for all $x\in M$ and $\parallel Ux\parallel =0$ for all $x\in M^{\perp}$.

Prove that if $\lambda$ is a eigenvalue of a partial isometry then $|\lambda|\leq 1$.

This problem was taken from Halmos's Finite Dimensional Vector Spaces (sec. 76).

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** what can you say about $\|U\|$? That's usually the first thing one should look when trying to estimate a spectral radius.

> Recall $V=M\oplus M^\perp$ for any subspace $M$ of a finite-dimensional inner-product space (or closed subspace of a Hilbert space, if you care about generalizing this fact). Then for every $v\in V$, we can write $v=x+y$ with $x\in M$ and $y\in M^\perp$. Hence $$\|v\|^2=\|x\|^2+\|y||^2\qquad Uv=Ux+Uy=Ux\quad\Rightarrow\quad \|Uv\|=\|Ux\|=\|x\|\leq \|v||.$$ Now just apply this to any eigenpair $(\lambda,v)$.

Comment: I was going to post the same answer. Good hint.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal Thank you, Mhenni.

Comment: Minor technicality: In the infinite dimensional case it should be assumed that $M$ is closed (or else we can just use its closure).  Although, given the title of the book, perhaps $V$ is implicitly assumed to be finite dimensional.

Comment: @JonasMeyer Right, but it is taken from Halmos FDVS. So that's why I decided to let this go. Thanks for the note.

Comment: What happens if $V$ is infinite dimensional and is not closed?

Comment: @Perguntador A partial isometry is usually an isometry on a closed space, null on the orthogonal complement. So it works the same. The only other situation I can think of would be: you have an isometry on $M$ not closed in $H$ Hilbert, you extend it to an isometry on $\overline{M}$ by uniform continuity. Then you extend it by $0$ on the orthogonal complement.